# Draw Rectangles in Area on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm drawing an area on Google Maps using the Geometry API. I want to know if it is possible to draw a repeating element onto an area that is dynamic in size?

For example, if I draw my area to look like this:

[image]

Then I want to be able to hit 'Next Step' and see something like this, with the rectangles drawn in the area, but only if they will fit. i.e., they have to be 'full' rectangles, not part rectangles:

[image]

The only problem is, I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. I would use HTML5 `<canvas>` but unfortunately, this needs to be as browser-friendly as possible, but if it has to be `<canvas>` then so be it!

Comment: This is really unrelated to answering your question, but out of sheer curiosity, if I may, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan At clients request..

Comment: Haha, yeah but what does he want to acomplish, for what purpose. Maybe you can find a workaround if you know the purpose.

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan, the purpose is exactly this unfortunately 8-), I need to be able to draw the maximum number of rectangles in the selected area as a visual aid for a process in an online application we're building.

Comment: Are the included rectangles a fixed size?

Comment: @davidstrachan - yes they are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Joshua M

Sorry for keeping you wait.
Ok, the new code is below.
You can specify the small box size at `var boxSize = new google.maps.Size(10, 20);`

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var mapCanvas, boxes = new google.maps.MVCArray();
      function initialize() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.422191,-122.084585),
          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
          zoom : 19,
          tilt : 0
        });


        //Encoded path
        var encodedPath = "eblcFnuchVv@D@q@P?a@eD]AC~@b@DCz@a@A";
        var points = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath);

        //Draw a polygon
        var polygonOpts = {
          paths : points,
          strokeWeight : 6,
          strokeColor : "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity : 1,
          //fillColor : "blue",
          fillOpacity : 0,
          map : mapCanvas,
          editable : true
        };
        var poly = new google.maps.Polygon(polygonOpts);


        var proc = function() {
          onPolygonComplete(poly);
        };
        google.maps.event.addListener(mapCanvas, "projection_changed", proc);
        google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'insert_at', proc);
        google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'remove_at', proc);
        google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'set_at', proc);
      }

      function onDrawMgr_complete(polygon) {
        var path = polygon.getPath();
        console.log(google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path));
      }

      function onPolygonComplete(polygon) {
        var bounds, paths, sw, ne, ystep, xstep, boxH, boxW, posArry, flag, pos, x, y, i, box;

        //Delete old boxes.
        boxes.forEach(function(box, i) {
          box.setMap(null);
          delete box;
        });

        //Calculate the bounds that contains entire polygon.
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        paths = polygon.getPath();
        paths.forEach(function(latlng, i) {
          bounds.extend(latlng);
        });

        var projection = mapCanvas.getProjection();
        var zoom = mapCanvas.getZoom();
        var powBase = Math.pow(2, zoom);

        //Calculate the small box size.
        sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
        ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var swPoint = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(sw);
        var nePoint = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(ne);
        var boxSize = new google.maps.Size(10, 20); //in pixels.
        boxSize.width /= powBase;
        boxSize.height /= powBase;
        var maxX = Math.floor(Math.abs((swPoint.x - nePoint.x)) / boxSize.width);
        var maxY = Math.floor(Math.abs((swPoint.y - nePoint.y)) / boxSize.height);


        for ( y = 0; y < maxY; y++) {
          for (x = 0; x < maxX; x++) {
            //Detect that polygon is able to contain a small box.
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            posArry = [];
            posArry.push(new google.maps.Point(swPoint.x + boxSize.width * x, swPoint.y - boxSize.height * y));
            posArry.push(new google.maps.Point(swPoint.x + boxSize.width * x, swPoint.y - boxSize.height * (y + 1)));
            posArry.push(new google.maps.Point(swPoint.x + boxSize.width * (x + 1), swPoint.y - boxSize.height * y));
            posArry.push(new google.maps.Point(swPoint.x + boxSize.width * (x + 1), swPoint.y - boxSize.height * (y + 1)));

            var flag = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < posArry.length; i++) {
              pos = projection.fromPointToLatLng(posArry[i]);
              if (flag) {
                flag = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(pos, polygon);
                bounds.extend(pos);
              }
            }

            if (flag) {
              box = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                bounds : bounds,
                map : mapCanvas,
                strokeColor : 'green',
                strokeOpacity : 1,
                strokeWeight : 1,
                fillColor : 'yellow',
                fillOpacity : 0.5,
                clickable : false
              });
              boxes.push(box);
            }
          }
        }
      }


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      window,html,#map_canvas{
        width : 700px;
        height : 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map_canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this but I have one question
Can't we declare the height and width of the box as per current zoom level in pixels like say I want a box to be drawn for 1 feet * 1 feet or 1meter *1meter instead of var boxSize = new google.maps.Size(10, 20); //in pixels. ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to know the scaling as well. How can we convert the square of 25 square meters into pixels? It should fix for all the zoom levels as well.

Answer (score 14):

Although I didn't use canvas, how about this code?

```
function onPolygonComplete(polygon) {
  var bounds, paths, sw, ne, ystep, xstep,
      boxH, boxW, posArry, flag, pos,
      x, y, i, box, maxBoxCnt;

  //Delete old boxes.
  boxes.forEach(function(box, i) {
    box.setMap(null);
    delete box;
  });

  //Calculate the bounds that contains entire polygon.
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  paths = polygon.getPath();
  paths.forEach(function(latlng, i){
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  });


  //Calculate the small box size.
  maxBoxCnt = 8;
  sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
  ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
  ystep = Math.abs(sw.lat() - ne.lat()) / maxBoxCnt;
  boxH = Math.abs(sw.lat() - ne.lat()) / (maxBoxCnt + 1);
  xstep = Math.abs(sw.lng() - ne.lng()) / maxBoxCnt;
  boxW = Math.abs(sw.lng() - ne.lng()) / (maxBoxCnt + 1);

  for (y = 0; y < maxBoxCnt; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < maxBoxCnt; x++) {
      //Detect that polygon is able to contain a small box.
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      posArry = [];
      posArry.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() + ystep * y, sw.lng() + xstep * x));
      posArry.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() + ystep * y, sw.lng() + xstep * x + boxW));
      posArry.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() + ystep * y + boxH, sw.lng() + xstep * x));
      posArry.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() + ystep * y + boxH, sw.lng() + xstep * x + boxW));
      flag = true;
      for (i = 0; i < posArry.length; i++) {
        pos = posArry[i];
        if (flag) {
          flag = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(pos, polygon);
          bounds.extend(pos);
        }
      }

      //Draw a small box.
      if (flag) {
        box = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          bounds : bounds,
          map : mapCanvas,
          strokeColor: '#00ffff',
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          fillColor: '#00ffff',
          fillOpacity : 0.5,
          clickable: false
        });
        boxes.push(box);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code works like this image.
[image]

I wrote a page that explains the code.
http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/poly_containsLocation.html

Comment: Excellent, this is so fantastic! However, I have one change that I can't figure out myself. I need the rectangles to be a finite width - I assumed that to change this it would be here? `boxH = Math.abs(sw.lat() - ne.lat()) / maxBoxCnt;`. For example; I need the boxes to be like 10 high, 5 wide, then put as many in as possible, rather than putting a finite number of boxes in regardless of the size of the area. Hope I make sense, thanks again, this will keep the ball rolling for now (unless the above isn't possible, then I'll let them know this!)

Comment: In example to the above, [This is putting 13 in a small area](http://i.imgur.com/3fRPS.png), [This is putting 14 in a huge area](http://i.imgur.com/JlNT0.png); What I want is that if it puts 13 in the smaller area at that size, keep that size permanent for all other sizes which are specified.

Comment: Are there the maximum number of boxes always 15? And don't you mind the box size?

Comment: @wf9a5m75, no. I need there to be a fixed box size and the maximum number of boxes is dependant on how many of those fixed boxes will fit into the area.

Comment: He's probably trying to show what "fits" in a certain area. You'll need to detect the current zoom level and scale a base box size appropriately.

Comment: Oh, thanks your advice. I'm on Thanks giving days. Sorry for waiting. I'll create later.