# How to make rectangle visible until another rectangle draw

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on google map. I get the bound values after draw rectangle successful.But the rectangle is not visible that is my problem. Please help me to visible rectangle until another rectangle draw.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/16/ please refer this link for code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381497/draw-rectangles-in-area-on-google-maps

  Try this.. i think this will give you an idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In on 'click' event listener for rectangle you are removing it by setting setMap(null), and then setting its bounds to minimal values. Probably you should remove these lines and on 'mousemove' event check 'state' variable instead of using getmap

```
if (state==1) {
    rect.setBounds(toBounds(pt1, event.latLng));
}
```

see updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/2306/)

Answer (score 0):

```
      function onPolygonComplete(polygon) {
     var bounds, paths, sw, ne, ystep, xstep,
     boxH, boxW, posArry, flag, pos,
     x, y, i, box, maxBoxCnt;

   //Delete old boxes.
   boxes.forEach(function(box, i) {
    box.setMap(null);
        delete box;
      });

     //Calculate the bounds that contains entire polygon.
       bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      paths = polygon.getPath();
     paths.forEach(function(latlng, i){
       bounds.extend(latlng);
       });


      //Calculate the small box size.
       maxBoxCnt = 8; 
     sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
      ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
       ystep = Math.abs(sw.lat() - ne.lat()) / maxBoxCnt;
        boxH = Math.abs(sw.lat() - ne.lat()) / (maxBoxCnt + 1);
       xstep = Math.abs(sw.lng() - ne.lng()) / maxBoxCnt;
      boxW = Math.abs(sw.lng() - ne.lng()) / (maxBoxCnt + 1); 

        for (y = 0; y < maxBoxCnt; y++) {
          for (x = 0; x < maxBoxCnt; x++) {
           //Detect that polygon is able to contain a small box.
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          posArry = [];
         posArry.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() + ystep * y, sw.lng() + xstep *     x));
  posArry.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() + ystep * y, sw.lng() + xstep * x + boxW));
  posArry.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() + ystep * y + boxH, sw.lng() + xstep * x));
  posArry.push(new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() + ystep * y + boxH, sw.lng() + xstep * x + boxW));
  flag = true;
  for (i = 0; i < posArry.length; i++) {
    pos = posArry[i];
    if (flag) {
      flag = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(pos, polygon);
      bounds.extend(pos);
    }
  }

  //Draw a small box.
  if (flag) {
    box = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds : bounds,
      map : mapCanvas,
      strokeColor: '#00ffff',
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillColor: '#00ffff',
      fillOpacity : 0.5,
      clickable: false
    });
    boxes.push(box);
  }
}
```

}
}

And refer this too Demo:**[Draw Rectangles in Area on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381497/draw-rectangles-in-area-on-google-maps)**

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i need to correct my code itself. thats only my problem now